# Unable to connect to nxserver

Tags: linux, freenx, nomachine

I've installed nx & freenx on a RHEL 6.3 via the 'yum install nx freenx' command. In the configuration file, node.conf, I've un-commented the following lines:

```
ENABLE_USERMODE_AUTHENTICATION="0"
ENABLE_PASSDB_AUTHENTICATION="0"
ENABLE_SSH_AUTHENTICATION="1"
```

On my mac client I have installed the NoMachine player and copied the client.id_dsa.key from the server. On the server I am able to successfully start the nxserver via the nxserver --start command. When I run nxserver --status I get the following output:

```
NX> 100 NXSERVER - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: not detected)
NX> 110 NX Server is running
NX> 999 Bye
```

So to me it means that the nexserver is running and indeed I'm able to telnet into the port. THe problem is that when I try to connect using my NoMachine client I get the following error almost instnantly:

```
The NoMachine service is not available or the NX access was disabled on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
```

Now I have the same setup on another computer and I've never had an issue with any of this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that it works on another computer, do you mean another MacOSX machine, with the same OS version ? Because I had many problems with the latest versions of MacOSX since it doesn't come with Rosetta anymore. You may want to try "opennx" instead of the Nomachine client.

Comment: The weird thing is that I have no problem logging into another computer, running nx and freenx, from the same Mac. I'll give opennx a try.

Comment: So I got rid of the NoMachine nxserver and instead installed neatx. I then used the opennx client as you suggested and voila everything works perfectly. I didn't have to setup any extra keys. I think with neatx as long as you can ssh into the computer, neatx just works out of the box which is very nice. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ssh to the server? Is there a firewall enabled on the Linux side (iptables)?

Isn't the version of Nomachine in freenx older than what's available via the [Nomachine website](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php)?

Comment: Yes I can ssh and iptables is enabled. I've installed no machine as you suggested and I actually get further this time; however, now it tells me that "Cannot start the requested session" and when I look at my logs on the client it says "NX> 595 ERROR: A fatal error occurred in NX Server." I looked at the logs on the server under /var/log/messages but they are too long to post here and I'm not sure how useful they would be. When Installing I just left everything as is and I copied the private key to my client for using the NoMachine login.